# 1000hz bootstrap validator custom

Tags: jquery, bootstrapvalidator-1000hz

I am having troubles getting a return string passed back to the validator.

Here is my js

```
$('#frmSignUp').validator({
        custom: {
            emailexist: function ($el) {
                var result = checkUserEmail($el.val())
                    .done(function (r) {
                        if (!r.success) {
                            // email already in use
                            return r;
                        } 
                    })
                return result.responseText;
            }
        }
    });

    function checkUserEmail(name) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckUserName","Account")',
            data: { ChapterPOCEmail: name },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

in chrome dev tools the "r" does indeed have the full json returned from the controller

> {"success":false,"responseText":"That email is already in use."}

However, the validator isn't receiving the string, and therefor is still showing the green check mark in the feedback, and no message in the help-block.  I have tried to use the "data-remote", but I couldn't get asp.net to return a status code along with a message correctly.  it was overriding any custom message I sent back , and the validator couldn't receive it.

Any help on my issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajax` is an async method [by deafult](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and does not return any value.

You can force it to be sync though or use promises, and use it's value on success for example...

change your `checkUserEmail` with this:

```
function checkUserEmail(name) {
    var r = false;

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CheckUserName","Account")',
        data: { ChapterPOCEmail: name },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false // wait for the call, dont treat as an async call
    }).done(function(result) {
        r = result === "OK";
    }).fail(function (err) {
        console.log(err, "something went awire");
    }).always(function () {
        console.log("all done");
    });

    return r;
}
```

I assume that your ajax call returns `OK`, remember to change it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you!  I new it had something to do with the async nature, but I couldn't wrap my head around the proper way to get it.